# Accessing phone contacts within Flex for mobile

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, contacts

I would like to create an app for Blackberry, iPhone and Android using Adobe Flex. But I need to access the phone's contacts and I can't seem to find a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

This information is not exposed via AIR for Mobile APIs.

You can't access them on all platforms; and the ones where you can require [complicated work arounds](http://www.jamesward.com/2011/05/11/extending-air-for-android/).

The next version of AIR should address this.  I expect we'll find out more at Adobe Max in October.

Comment: So this means that the next version possibly will support managing contacts on many platforms?

Comment: I found this little app that does some SQL queries but I dont think this is cross platform, right? http://www.flextechie.com/my-first-flex-mobile-application-contact-mobile-app/comment-page-1

Comment: @Harry Stroker I'm not sure of specific Native APIs; but the next version of Flex will allow you to extend Flex/AIR with native code.  I don't know anything about that app, sorry.